# Electric car battery weight: understand question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, work, batteries

Could you please assist an absolute beginner in understanding the core aspects of this problem and the relevant topics necessary for solving it, as well as specific of electric-car that should be used in the problem?

The problem begins with the statement that there is an electric car and when the gas pedal was released the car started slowly reduce its speed. Specifically, the speed was reduced from 100 to 80 km/h within 10 seconds.

This car must drive to the destination 100 km away and return to the starting point with the remaining 20% battery capacity. How much % of the total mass of the machine will be occupied by batteries if Lithium-ion cells are used, where the mass of one cell is 45 g, the nominal voltage is 3.7V and the capacity is 3000 mAh?

1. How data about car's ability to reduce speed from 100 to 80 can help with battery weight? Is it relevant at all to the question?
2. I believe we should calculate energy consumed during the 100km drive to the destination. This 20% sentence is a bit misleading form me. Do we use 20% of battery for 200km or 20% on way back 100km?
3. I understand that I have to calculate how many Li-ion cells I need, using given data about 1 cell. 3000 * 3.7/1000 = 11.1 wH

Comment: When the car is slowing down, the motors are used as generators to charge the batteries. As this charge is generated while driving, this charge is in effect additional to the battery capacity. Hence a possible reduction in battery weight.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Clearly a conceptual question about what method to use, not a "do my homework" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How data about car's ability to reduce speed from 100 to 80 can help with battery weight? Is it relevant at all to the question?

A electric car has to use the energy in its batteries to counteract the effect of air friction on the car.  It has to do work according to $W=Fd$.  The little experiment where we let off the gas and observe how fast the car slows down can be used to calculate what the force of air friction is.  (well, we can get close.  I'm guessing you're expected to assume a constant force at all speeds, which is not realistic.   [Drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)) is better modeled as proportional to the square of velocity.  However, given that the problem doesn't state the speed you intend to go 100km at, I'm guessing they're just hand-waving it as a constant force at all speeds.

> 2. I believe we should calculate energy consumed during the 100km drive to the destination (and it would be maybe 80% of battery capacity?). Thou, I actually do not get how electric car works if to one direction it uses 80% of battery, but back it uses only 20%, how this is even possible?

You didn't quote the actual wording of the question, so there's no way we can be sure.  However, if I venture a guess, it is likely they want to do the entire round trip with 20% battery remaining.  Thus they need to travel 200km using 80% of the energy in the batteries.

> 3. I understand that I have to calculate how many Li-ion cells I need, using given data about 1 cell. 3000 * 3.7/1000 = 11.1 wH

This seems reasonable on the surface.  Without actually seeing the question, I don't think we can suggest otherwise.

Comment: This is the exact wording: "This car must drive to the destination 100 km away and returned to the starting point with the remaining 20% battery capacity. How much % of the total mass of the machine will be occupied by batteries if Lithium-ion cells are used, where the mass of one cell is 45 g, the nominal voltage is 3.7V and the capacity is 3000 mAh? This 20% is misleading in the question in the original wording. Do we use 20% for 200km or 100km (way back).

Comment: I would *assume* they intend you to use 200km, based on the fact that this is a homework problem and that's the way they get worded.  In the real world, obviously an electric car owner would plug in and charge when they reached the destination, which would suggest actually needing to size it for 100km.  However, given this is a homework problem and they added the phrase "and returned to the starting point," it sounds like they intend that phrase to matter.  The only way it can matter is if the car doesn't charge at the destination, and has to make the full 200km on one charge.